# TabBar hides in viewDidLoad but doesnt in gesture function

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, viewcontroller

I tried calling `tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = true` in viewDidLoad() and it hides the TabBar. However, I tried to set tap gesture and hide the bar on Tap. The parent viewController that has ScrollView inside it with subview (that is connected with IBOutlet as `myView`)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
   print("A") // logs successfully
           if TabBarHidden == false {
               print("B") // logs successfully

               //I tried:
               tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true

               // I also tried
               tabBarController?.tabBar.alpha = 0
               tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.x += 50
               hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true


           } else {
               ...
               TabBarHidden = false
           }
    }
```

`hidden` does work when I call it in viewDidLoad as I said, but not if I call in tap gesture function. What may be the problem? What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure `tabBarController` and `tabBar ` are not nil.

Comment: Make sure you're running this in the UI thread.  When you try to do UI things in a background thread weird things can happen...

Comment: @Putz1103 How can I make sure of that? @Jelly, I tried `print(tabBarController!.tabBar)`, it returns. :/ Bare in mind, `tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true` works if I call it in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: where do you set `TabBarHidden = true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code totally works for me:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var tabBarHidden: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = tabBarHidden
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapGestureRecognized(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func tapGestureRecognized(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        tabBarHidden = !tabBarHidden
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work. It doesn't let me use the `action:` you have. I tired it with my Selector style, and consoled it in the method. However, it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: try `let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:))` and see if the method gets called...

Comment: It forces me to use ` action: Selector("tapGestureRecognized:") and it gets called inside the function. However, tabBarHidden doesn't work :/ If I call    `tabBarHidden = !tabBarHidden` inside the viewDidLoad() it does work too. However, it doesn't work in function. :/

Comment: this is weird. wanna share your project so i can take a deeper look?

Comment: Maybe it is caused because I am using a library called [Animated TabBar](https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar). I better create an issue there. Thanks anyway! I am pretty sure it's caused by the library and your code works, because it works for me in viewDidLoad. Thanks a lot for the tip though!